# R shortest.paths for loops

Tags: r, performance, igraph, shortest-path

I have a task to **repeat the function shortest.paths,but my input is too large**.I wanna know **how to get it fast**.To all my known, the **igraph** is the best choice. My kernel is as follows:

First, I got a real network and 1000 random network as 'list' format

```
library(igraph)
# real ppi network
REAL.PPI <- paste0(RANDM, "real.ppi.txt")
real.ppi <- graph.data.frame(read.table(REAL.PPI, header = F), directed = F)
ppi.gs <- V(real.ppi)$name
# random network
random_net_names <- dir(paste0(RANDM, "randomnetwork"))
random_nets <- lapply(random_net_names, function(x){
  path <- paste(RANDM, "randomnetwork/", x, sep="")
  rn <- read.table(path, header = F)
  graph.data.frame(rn, directed = F)
}
```

Then, I have to **compare the node sets' shortest paths in real and random networks**.For this, I choose for-loop instead apply-function because the latter will not be faster.

input format is as:

```
hsa-let-7a-2-3p hsa-let-7a-3p   GO:0001702  4040    10818   4089
hsa-let-7a-2-3p hsa-let-7a-3p   GO:0001764  27185   2625    5048    429 6695
```

My kernel is as follows:

```
# input
ovr <- strsplit(readLines("ovr.txt"), '\t')
# for-loop
OUT.final <- outfile("out.txt", "w")
for(i in 1 : length(ovr)){
  hyper.ppi.ovr <- ovr[[i]][- c(1, 2, 3)]
  D1 <- shortest.paths(real.ppi, hyper.ppi.ovr, hyper.ppi.ovr)
  CPLs <- sapply(random_nets, function(r_net){
    sum(shortest.paths(r_net, hyper.ppi.ovr, hyper.ppi.ovr)) 
  }
  )
  D2.p <- sum(CPLs < D1) / 1000
  if(D2.p > .01)next
  # output
  out.value <- ovr[[i]]
  cat(out.value, sep = "\t", file = OUT.final)
  cat("\n", file = OUT.final)
}
close(OUT.final)
```

Comment: Of cource, there maybe other language accelerating the proceccing just like 'python', which contains the package 'igraph' as well.But, what i wish is just using R to speed up.

Comment: This is a very pythonic way of writing code ;p. Throw a bigger dataset into a pastebin or something so I can make a few checks? It's fine if it's randomly-generated.